# truncate core_url_rewrite by cron

Tags: magento-1.9, database, url-rewrite

Is it possible to truncate this table by cron? It seems to be necessary because in few days the table's weight increases to about 10GB.

Answer (score 0):

wow, this will broke all SEO Strategy. Do not do this.

Magento 1 have a bug in url-rewrites and regenerated urls on every product save (after editing) and create multiple variants of urls for single product.

You can use this module to fix it. https://github.com/riznmage/Rizn_FixUrlRewrites